# newbie just got a d3200

Tags: nikon

I'm quite new to photography in general I've mainly in the past tried to get killer camera phone shots, now the missis has just got me a used d3200 for my birthday, it's body only so has no lens I'm looking at picking up a cheap 18-55mm vr for it to be going on with and keeping my eye out for bargains, but also I'm looking at some sort lenses for the olden film days any advice appreciated.

I've read that Sir lenses are obviously missing features like auto focus which I don't find a problem, metering and iso etc I would like to learn more about and I think an sir lens is a good way to go about it and they seem pretty cheap, my main question is will all nikon lenses fit (presuming their all F-mounts?)

thanks..

Comment: pitty you have little more to do than complain about my question, if it's a duplicate I could not care less I have worded my question the way I wanted to, but I guess your the usual forum half watts..

Answer (score 0):

You should get the latest and best version of 18-55, as it's cheap enough.

Sadly D3200 is not a good camera for old lenses. All F mount will fit (except the oldest ones), but as you already know that everything will be manual. What you may not realize that it means you need to repeat same shot over and over basically shooting blind as camera will have no idea what aperture is set. It might be a way to learn something but don't expect to get any useful shouts.

Here's a chart of what features are missing on which types of lens: http://kenrockwell.com/nikon/compatibility-lens.htm#dslr

Comment: thanks that's a helpful link, I picked one of these up I know it won't auto focus but for the price I paid it will serve me well and I won't be using it for everyday pics..

Nikon AF Nikkor 28-100mm 1:3.5-5.6G lens